# How to approach integrals as a function?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve the following question involving integrals, and can't quite get what am I supposed to do:

$$f(x) = \int_{2x}^{x^2}\root 3\of{\cos z}~dz$$
$$f'(x) =\ ?$$

How should I approach such integral functions? Am I just over-complicating a simple thing?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule for differentiation?

Comment: Yes, I do; I tried messing with this integral around, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but wasn't quite sure I'm on the right path. I've ended up with a weird expression that I'm not sure is correct/final answer.
I've tried gathering information from wolframalpha, but it doesn't seem to handle such functions/integrals. Could you direct me to the right way - what should I end with?

Comment: @Sam: That looks interesting; Could you explain how it can be used here?

Comment: You could first split the integral into two integrals: $\int_{2x}^{x^2} \root3\of{\cos z}\,dz =\int_{2x}^0\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz+\int_0^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz=-\int_0^{2x}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz+\int_0^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz$, and then use Tim's hint in his comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this problem, you will ultimately use a version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: If $f$ is continuous, then the function $F$ defined by $F(x)=\int_a^x f(z)\,dz$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x)$.

So for instance, for $F(x)=\int_0^x\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz$, we have $F'(x)=\root3\of{\cos x}$.

One can combine this with the chain rule, when it applies, to differentiate a function whose rule is of the form $F(x)=\int_a^{g(x)} f(z)\,dz$. Here, we recognize that $F$ is a composition of the form $F=G\circ g$ with $G(x)=\int_a^x f(z)\,dz$.  The  derivative is $F'(x)=\bigl[ G(g(x))\bigr]'=G'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)=f(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$.

For example, for $F(x)=\int_0^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz$, we have $F'(x)=\root3\of{\cos x^2}\cdot(x^2)'=2x\root3\of{\cos x^2} $.

Now to tackle your problem proper and take advantage of these rules, we just "split the integral":
$$\tag{1}
\int_{2x}^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz=
\int_{2x}^{0}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz+
\int_{0}^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz.
$$
But wait! We can only use the aforementioned differentiation rules for functions defined by an integral when it's the *upper* limit of integration that is the variable.  The first integral in the right hand side of $(1)$ does not satisfy this.  Things are easily remedied, though; write the right hand side of $(1)$ as:
$$
-\int_{0}^{2x}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz+
\int_{0}^{x^2}\root3\of{\cos z}\,dz;
$$
and now things are set up to use our rule (of course, you'll also use the rule $[cf+g]'=cf'+g'$).

Comment: Such a well written answer. Wish I could up-vote it a few more times; Thank you so much

Comment: @dvir, I did it for you.

Answer (score 4):

Not to give it away completely. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $f(x) = C(x^2)-C(2x)$, where $C(x)$ is the anti-derivative of the integrand. Now, use the Chain rule to compute $f'(x)$, which will depend only on the $C'(x)$, which is the integrand itself, evaluated at $x$.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x)&=&(x^2)'(\sqrt[s]{\cos z})|_{z=x^2}-(2x)'(\sqrt[s]{\cos z})|_{z=2x}\cr
&=&2x\sqrt[s]{\cos x^2}-2\sqrt[s]{\cos 2x}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Then show us what you think is correct!

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $ 2x\root s\of{\cos x^2} - 2\root s\of{\cos 2x} $ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to differentiate an integral of the form:

$$\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}f(z)dz$$

we use Leibniz rule.  First assume that $F(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $f(x)$.  That is $F'(x) = f(x)$. Then it follows that,

$$\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}f(z)dz = F(z)|_{z=g_2(x)} - F(z)|_{z=g_1(x)} = F(g_2(x)) - F(g_1(x))$$

Now if we differentiate this result using the chain rule we get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(g_2(x)) - F(g_1(x))\right) = f(g_2(x))g_2'(x) - f(g_1(x))g_1'(x).$$

Note that it is not necessary to find the anti-derivative $F()$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Leibnitz rule of differentiation of integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits_form), 
which states that if
\begin{align}
f(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(y) \ dy,
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x) = g(b(x)) b^{\prime}(x) - g(a(x)) a^{\prime}(x).
\end{align}
Thus, for your problem $a^{\prime}(x) = 2$ and $b^{\prime}(x) = 2x$ and, therefore, 
\begin{align}
f^{\prime}(x) = \int_{2x}^{x^2} \sqrt[3]{\cos z} dz = \sqrt[3]{\cos (x^2)} (2 x) - \sqrt[3]{\cos (2x)} (2).
\end{align}

Comment: The downvote seems a bit harsh.